# How do I make a "signup with Github" button like the one on Coderwall?

Tags: oauth, github, github-api

Is there any documentation about using github to authenticate users on my site? Preferably in PHP.

Like the button here: http://coderwall.com/

Comment: Well, there's [this](http://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, it's documented in the [OAuth section](http://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/) of the GitHub API [documentation](http://developer.github.com/).

There's also [an example implementation](http://developer.github.com/guides/basics-of-authentication/) in Github's documentation guides.

Comment: I'm not seeing any info on how to make a button on the links provided, did the docs change? I have my OAuth working I would just like a nice button instead of a simple link. Can someone please help?

Comment: @chaddienhart as I can see on coderwall they are using [fontawesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/)

Answer (score 15):

The example provided by Github and shared by Adrian Petrescu is great and is as simple as it gets.

However, I find that most OAuth examples are missing 2 things:

1. How to create a proper 'Login with ....' button on your page. Sounds easy but if you google around, you will encounter mostly CSS hacks, which is not ideal
2. A sandbox with all the pieces of OAuth code that is already up and running so that you can poke around it to get a better understanding. Without this, an OAuth newbie has to spend hours trying to setup different pieces (OAuth provider app, front-end, back-end), before he can get started. More likely than not she may make a mistake in one of the pieces, and spend hours debugging it.

So we created [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dg9h7dse/30/), with accompanying detailed explanation here on [coderwall](https://coderwall.com/p/sjbwcq/javascript-github-social-login-button-for-oauth?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=answer). You can use this immediately to test out an OAuth provider's API endpoints.

I'll summarize it here:

1. To create a nice social button:

- use [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com), [Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/icons), [bootstrap-social](https://lipis.github.io/bootstrap-social/);
- add this snippet:

```html
<a id="github-button" class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-github">
  <i class="fa fa-github"></i> Sign in with GitHub
</a>
```

2. For us to put the demo code on jsfiddle for people to play around with, we needed a front-end only OAuth solution, so we use [https://oauth.io](https://oauth.io?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=answer), which has a [Javascript front-end only library](https://github.com/oauth-io/oauth-js) that works with the service.

NOTE: [https://oauth.io](https://oauth.io?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=answer) is a paid-service but lets you integrate with hundreds(?) of OAuth providers without writing backend code.

All we need to do then is to bind our nice social login button to a Javascript snippet that calls the OAuth service provider.

```js
$('#github-button').on('click', function() {
  // Initialize with your OAuth.io app public key
  OAuth.initialize('YOUR OAUTH.IO PUBLIC KEY');
  // Use popup to prompt user for their OAuth provider credentials
  OAuth.popup('github').then(github => {
    // If login is successful,
    // retrieve user data from oauth provider
    console.log(github.me());
  });
})
```

Hope this helps more people to understand and get started on using OAuth.